# How to make Drives visible to OS using MegaCLI / MegaRAID not puting them in to RAID at all?

Tags: hard-disk, raid, software-raid

So I have 12 `[12:0-12]` drives that are "Unconfigured Good" as WebBIOS would say. They are not in any virtual drive span or drive group. I want to use software ZFS RAID instead of hardware one.  How to make my drives visiable to OS keeping them as seprate drives (not putting them into any kind of RAID)?

Answer (score 1):

You will find that you can present them as individual JBODs to the OS.  Then you may configure these devices as you see fit.  I ditched MegaRAID after three different attempts to get a card model that didn't fall over senselessly.  I hope you have MUCH better results than I did.  (aacraid now)

(On HP bioses, we found we had to make a series of one-disk RAID0s.  ugh, but it works)

Comment: Note that the terminology varies: it could be "JBOD", "pass-through", "raw disk", etc.